# How to change the size of PyQt5 directory view in the main window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtreeview

I am working on a PyQt5 project, which needs a folder viewer by PyQt5 `QTreeView`. In order to put more stuff, I try to change the size of the tree view but in vain. Here is the code from Pythonspot:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 file system view - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.tree.setWindowTitle("Dir View")
        self.tree.resize(640, 200)

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I change the tree view by

```
self.tree.resize(640, 200)
```

Why it does not function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layout is used to establish the position and size of the widget you are using, so in your case even if you use resize the size will not be changed, instead you should set a fixed size so the layout can not change the size of the `QTreeView`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 file system view - pythonspot.com'
        self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height = 10, 10, 640, 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.tree.setWindowTitle("Dir View")
        self.tree.setFixedSize(640, 200)

        windowLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.tree, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand

Comment: If I want to move the tree view by the following line? self.tree.move(200,100)

Comment: @TimChen then do not use a layout, for it eliminates: `windowLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.tree, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)` and change `self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()` to `self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)` and change `self.tree.setFixedSize(640, 200)` to `self.tree.setGeometry(200, 100, 640, 200)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! And if I want to have a popout window once I double-click a file in the directory view, could I add one line: `itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.buildExamplePopup)` in initUI(self). And add a function below: `def buildExamplePopup(self, item):
        exPopup = ExamplePopup(item.text(), self)
        exPopup.setGeometry(100, 200, 300, 300)
        exPopup.show()`